# How to pass from coordinates of an image to ARKit World Coordinates?

Tags: swift, coordinates, arkit

I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

### Introduction: Explanation of the project & goals

I have a white A4 sheet paper on which I drawn a *circuit* with a pen:

[image]

I detect this image with `ARKit RectangleDetection` and I save this image which will be used as texture.

Then I anchor a `SCNPlane` on this image and I setup the saved image as this plane's `texture`.

### What I need?

The **goal** is to convert SCNPlane coordinates in texture coordinates (of the 2D image used as texture). I don't understand how to get a point on the image and get tha same point on the SCNPlane. How to do that?

---

I've updated this post and I'll post the solution too :)

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow, and congrats on your project! It seems really interesting! Now, I have a couple of questions: 1) Have you considered using ARKit's image tracking feature instead of Vision? I don't know if it works in this situation, but it would be easier than using Vision. 2) Have you tried to use hitTest() to get the coordinates that you want? It seems to do exactly what you want (get 3D coordinates from 2D).

Comment: Hello, thank you @Andy :). Premise: I started my project from [this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_altering_images). 

1) I'm actually using `ARImageTrackingConfiguration`. I'll update my description above :).
2) I read about it but maybe I haven't understood properly how it works uhm. It's some like [that](https://i.imgur.com/PhNdh5v.jpg)? For use it I'll need a `planeDetection` and a `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`? Can you pilot me to the right usage of it?

Comment: One last thing: there are different types of `hitTest()` functions like `ARFrame hitTest(_:types:)`, `ARSCNView hitTest(_:types:)`, `SCNSceneRenderer
hitTest(_:types:)`. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @G.L.Paduano, Do you need both – an `image recognition` feature with ARImageAnchor and `plane detection` feature with ARPlaneAnchor ?? Please give me a link to video showing any similar project. I can't clearly understand what you need...

Comment: Oh ok, since you mentioned that project, I think things will be easier. From what I understood, you want to process the image (e.g., extract the drawn race track) and create virtual elements that represent your drawing. If this is right, you can add new nodes (e.g., car, race track, etc.) as children of your `SCNNode` (`VisualizationNode`) in the 2D coordinate system of `VisualizationNode` (z = 0). If my understanding is right, I can create an answer and elaborate a little more. Let me know if you want this.

Comment: @Andy I only need to track the image. After the application starts, the first think it does is to use Vision to detect rectangles in the scene. The rectangle detected will be the image to be processes. Please, look the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=111qv3IIZeM&feature=youtu.be). It explains clearly what it does :). To notice that the image is not pre-loaded in the app. Once the app recognizes a rectangle, this one will be the image to track.

Comment: @MarcelAlves yes, exaclty. I want to represent on the real image (in the real world) a virtual object that is identical to the circuit drawn on the paper. The idea is to use 2D coordinates of the image extracted as a basis for the 3D coordinates of the nodes to add (circuit's node, car's node, ecc...). I updated with a new image which gives better idea of what I want to achieve :).

Comment: @MarcelAlves in the reference project from which I started _the sample’s VisualizationNode fades between two images of differing style, which creates the effect that the tracked image is constantly transforming into a new look_. I'm not interested to this feature :). Of the mentioned project I only took the "image extraction with Vision".

Comment: @G.L.Paduano, got it! I will try to describe the general steps to solve this based on what you described, but I won't be able to provide detailed code, unfortunately, because it's not exactly a trivial task.

Comment: @MarcelAlves yes sir! I'll try to interpret your steps :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a coordinates conversion.

The following image gives the general idea:

[image: Change coordinates]

So, using this formula I can pass through two type of coordinates: *texture coordinates* and *SCNPlane coordinates*.

Using the following function I can make both coordinates conversions (from SCNPlane -> to Texture) (from Texture -> to SCNPlane).

```
func changeIntervalSheetSCNPlane(typeOfConversion: Bool, convStruct: ConversionSheetSCNPlane) -> SCNVector3 {

// Formula
//
//  NOTE:
//  - x € [xA, xB]  | y € [yA, yB]
//  - x' € [x'A, x'B]  | y' € [y'A, y'B]        x' = "x primo"
//
// x-xA/xB-xA = x'-x'A/x'B-x'A  => x' = (x'B-x'A/xB-xA)*(x-xA)+x'A
// y-yA/yB-yA = y'-y'A/y'B-y'A  => y' = (y'B-y'A/yB-yA)*(y-yA)+y'A
//
// x,y = Sheet  | x',y' = SCNPlane

var x: Float, y: Float, xP: Float, yP: Float,
    xPB: Float?, xPA: Float?, xB: Float?, xA: Float?,
    yPB: Float?, yPA: Float?, yB: Float?, yA: Float?

if (typeOfConversion) {
    x = Float(convStruct.sheetXYPoint!.x)
    y = Float(convStruct.sheetXYPoint!.y)

    // Calculate x' value
    xPB = Float(convStruct.planeTopRightPoint.x)
    xPA = Float(convStruct.planeTopLeftPoint.x)

    xB = Float(convStruct.sheetTopRightPoint.x)
    xA = Float(convStruct.sheetTopLeftPoint.x)

    // Calculate y' value
    yPB = Float(convStruct.planeTopRightPoint.y)
    yPA = Float(convStruct.planeBottomLeftPoint.y)

    yB = Float(convStruct.sheetTopRightPoint.y)
    yA = Float(convStruct.sheetBottomLeftPoint.y)
} else {
    x = Float(convStruct.planeXYPoint!.x)
    y = Float(convStruct.planeXYPoint!.y)

    // Calculate x' value
    xPB = Float(convStruct.sheetTopRightPoint.x)
    xPA = Float(convStruct.sheetTopLeftPoint.x)

    xB = Float(convStruct.planeTopRightPoint.x)
    xA = Float(convStruct.planeTopLeftPoint.x)

    // Calculate y' value
    yPB = Float(convStruct.sheetTopRightPoint.y)
    yPA = Float(convStruct.sheetBottomLeftPoint.y)

    yB = Float(convStruct.planeTopRightPoint.y)
    yA = Float(convStruct.planeBottomLeftPoint.y)
}

let xPB_xPA = xPB!-xPA!                             // (x'B-x'A)
let xB_xA = xB!-xA!                                 // (xB-xA)
let x_xA = x-xA!                                    // (x-xA)
xP = (xPB_xPA/xB_xA)*(x_xA)+xPA!                    // x'

let yPB_yPA = yPB!-yPA!                             // (y'B-y'A)
let yB_yA = yB!-yA!                                 // (yB-yA)
let y_yA = y-yA!                                    // (y-yA)
yP = (yPB_yPA/yB_yA)*(y_yA)+yPA!                     // y'

let position = SCNVector3(xP, yP, 0)

return position
}
```

The following structure defines the edges of Texture and SCNPlane and the point P(x,y) and P'(x',y') of the formula.

```
// Structure that contains the edges of Texture and SCNPlane
struct ConversionSheetSCNPlane {

// ========== TEXTURE ==========
// Point (X,Y) of the texture
public var sheetXYPoint: CGPoint?

// The four texture edge coordinates
public var sheetTopLeftPoint: CGPoint
public var sheetTopRightPoint: CGPoint
public var sheetBottomLeftPoint: CGPoint
public var sheetBottomRightPoint: CGPoint

// ========== SCNPLANE ==========
// Point (X,Y) of the plane
public var planeXYPoint: CGPoint?

// The four plane edge coordinates
public var planeTopLeftPoint: CGPoint
public var planeTopRightPoint: CGPoint
public var planeBottomLeftPoint: CGPoint
public var planeBottomRightPoint: CGPoint
}
```

Comment: Hello, just wondering for ARfacetracking, did you use this to covert it from 3D to 2D texture?

Comment: Hi, my solution is used to convert from SCNPlane 3D coordinates to 2D texture coordinates, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended to be a high-level description of what I think it could be done to solve your problem. Unfortunately, I won't be able to give a detailed description with code, but I hope this can be of any help.

## First Approach

Use a known image on your paper, set this image to be a reference image, and track this image with ARKit.

Basically, you will draw your elements using this image as a known point in space. See the image below for more context.

[image]

Tracking the known image, you will have a [SCNNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) that represents this image, and, if I'm not mistaken, its local coordinate system origin is on its center (as depicted). You can add children to this node, and they will be in the coordinate system of the known image, i.e., the x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis will be the same as the A4 paper.

In the depicted situation, *x_a* > 0, and *y_a* < 0, while *x_b* > 0, and *y_b* > 0, if the positive x-axis goes right, and the positive y-axis goes up (you will need to confirm this, because I'm not sure).

## Second Approach

This is more similar to what you want, but it's harder. You would use the signs that you've drawn as references. You could map from the real-paper coordinate system to ARKit coordinate system by performing hit tests (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest)) on 3 known points, which define a plane.

You don't need the user to touch the screen to perform a hit test. All you need are coordinates on normalized image coordinate space. This step will go after you process your image. I think it would be like this:

**Image Processing**

1. You execute the filters you need to extract the information you want;
2. As an additional step, the filter should identify 3 known points, which can be used to create a plane;
3. You add your elements relative to this plane.

The problem with this approach? I think there's no easy way to do this on ARKit, so you would need to implement most of the logic.

## Final Words

Going with the first approach is way easier, so I would go with that for an initial prototype. Maybe later you could change for a more advanced approach.

Anyway, I think the most complicated step is the image processing. If you can extract the information you want from the paper, you probably will be able to use either approach to draw your elements.

Comment: **First Approach:** supposing to have a known image (real) and its SCNNode (ARKit scene). Supposing to have the A4 paper (real) and add it as a child of SCNNode knows image (ARKit). How can I extract the circuit on the A4 paper having this situation? I don't understand reasoning about it uhm.

Comment: Extracting the circuit is part of the image processing step, which is really difficult, and I believed it wasn't part of the question. This is kind of unrelated to ARKit itself. Ignoring the 3D part, do you know how to extract the coordinates of your circuit in the A4 paper?

Comment: The idea is to work with the extracted image pixels and later convert from 2D coordinates to 3D coordinates. When I use Vision and it detects a rectangle, it returns a CVPixelBuffer. After applying the filter to fix image distortion, I finally get an image in a format (like CIImage) called `referenceImagePixelBuffer` and, later, I suppose to work with its pixels. The problem is how to pass from this pixels in 2D coordinates to 3D pixels in the ARKit scene... I don't figure out it.

Do you have any idea of the entire process?

Comment: Let's say you have access to the pixels of a 210x293 pixel buffer (these are the sizes of A4 paper in mm) called **PB**. In **First Approach**, if you can 1) identify the center of the known image (**KI**) in PB, and 2) identify the coordinates of your circuit in PB, you can create a virtual circuit with SceneKit by using the center of KI as the origin. E.g., If the center of KI in PB is (10,10) and you want to draw the PB point (25,35) with SceneKit, you add a point with coordinates (25-10,35-10) as a child of the node of the KI.

Comment: I know it's a lot of stuff, but you can just think of the known image as the origin and orientation that you will need to draw more objects, relative to this image. A more difficult part, as I said, is processing this pixel buffer. Not only you need to filter the pixels properly, but also you have to convert from pixels to meters. The only problem is that this is a little beyond the scope of the current question, imho, and I think it's a little too broad. If you have the coordinates in the Pixel Buffer, I can show you how to do these steps, but the question need to be narrowed down to this.

Comment: In other words, if you have an array of 2D coordinates in PixelBuffer coordinate system AND the 2D coordinate of the center of the known image in PixelBuffer coordinate system, I can give you a function to convert this array to an array in ARKit coordinate system - but the general idea is already what I described.

Comment: I’m referring to your first comment: Should I use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/giln/af6fdb5d6a5ead8686e42fbb4dd36ddd#file-cvpixelbuffer-swift-L19) to read each pixel? Supposing to get the <x,y> coordinates of each pixel I’m interested in, how can I convert these coordinates in SCNNode coordinates? `SCNNode` uses `SCNVector3`. Should I convert each pixel in CGPoint and later in SCNVector3?

Comment: Reading the pixels and extracting the information you need from an image is another issue. I recommend that you create another question for this purpose or try to figure this out before revisiting the coordinate system conversion problem. You should break this problem into smaller problems otherwise you won't get a satisfying answer. One thing that I can tell you in advance is that you will need a better way to represent your drawings than raw pixels because passing every pixel to ARKit is a bad idea.

Comment: I’m referring to your second comment: Can you show me how to do it? Maybe we can comunicate better on another communication app and after solved the problem, I can update this post correctly with all your reference and answers :). Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210313/discussion-between-g-l-paduano-and-marcel-alves).